# xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode45-DP1.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)

Tags: xcode4.4

I've been beating my head against the desk all day trying to fix this!!!

I have tried the suggested `xcode-select -switch /path/to/xcode/` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456918/change-xcrun-developer-path) but it still gives me this error!

I have now completely removed XCode 4.4 and the command line tools as well, and running the `xcrun` still gives me this error!

Even installing a new copy of Xcode and the command line tools produces this error!!

Result of commands..

```
sh-3.2# xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sh-3.2# xcrun -find
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode45-DP1.app/Contents/Developer'.           (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score -11, accepted):

The solution that finally worked was by reinstalling 10.8, reinstalling Xcode, and then reinstalling the command line tools.

Comment: Aaron's answer a better solution.

Comment: Issue was fixed by Aaron's fix.

Comment: No, it was not. Only after reinstalling Mountain Lion did it work.

Comment: I can't understand, why people minus this answer. Probably it's not the best solution, but solution anyway. 

P.S. I tried both answers above and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I feel that Aarons should be the correct answer.  I did it and in 1 shot, evyerhting works.

Comment: Aarons answer is the correct answer with `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` instead

Answer (score 209):

## Solution #1 (affects all users)

`xcode-select` is the answer.  You are either pointing at the wrong path or you are not doing it as a root user.  Try this in Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

and then type your password.

## Solution #2 (affects only you)

If

- you don't want to `sudo`, or
- you don't have superuser permissions, or
- solution #1 doesn't work

override the DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable instead:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

**Optional**: you can make this persist between login sessions by editing your **[.bash_profile](http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac)** file.

If neither solution works, post your error message.

Comment: Also note that you no longer have to point to the Developer folder inside the app, you can just point to the app now.

Comment: @David (1) Did you try running the `xcode-select` under `sudo`?  (2) `xcrun` requires a specific utility parameter.  For whatever command you're trying to do, try adding the `--kill-cache` parameter, like `xc-run --kill-cache xcode-select` for example.

Comment: @Aaron I tried xcrun --kill-cache xcode-select, but it says again: could not stat active Xcode path

Comment: @Aaron Do you know where to find config file for that?

Comment: @Flink I think it's in a database, not an easy-to-edit text file, which is why they have this app.  What is the output of `xcode-select --print-path`?

Comment: @Flink Also, I'm wondering if you are running an older version of the command line tools.  What if you `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`?

Comment: @Flink To update your command line tools, go to **Xcode** -> **Preferences** -> **Downloads** -> **Command Line Tools** -> **Update**.

Comment: @Aaron xcode-select --print-path gives right path: /Applications/Xcode.app. No, I use the latest command tools...

Comment: @Flink the `--print-path` command should return `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.  Did you try `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`?  If not, sure, give reinstallation a whirl, it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: I changed that, but problem still exists. I'll try to reinstall.
Thanks anyway for helping me ;)

Comment: FWIW, this fixed my borked gitlab vagrant install: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-vagrant-vm

Comment: i've tried `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` and that solved the problem

Comment: You just helped me with the same problem after installing Xcode 5 preview. No luck with xcode-select -switch, but exporting the DEVELOPER_DIR did the trick.

Comment: I encountered this error after I renamed my Xcode app to Xcode5 in order to distinguish it from Xcode4.6.3 in the dock. Then the recommended solution worked great, with the path set to match - i.e., /Applications/Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that `/usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link` points to an old folder,
and doesn't updates when command

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` is executed.

**Solution**: delete this link and create it manually.

Comment: I don't see /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link (or even /usr/share/xcode-select/) when using the current version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` didn't work for me, but this did.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work if I don't have XCode installed, only the command line tools

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

1. XCode preferences/Locations/Command Line Tools - set to proper version and location
2. XCode preferences/Downloads - install command line tools

Answer (score 2):

Solutions above didn't help me.
Removing old system links helped me. 
It is described here: 
[Error: Can't run /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool (no such file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423215/error-cant-run-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-platforms-macosx-pla)

Answer (score 2):

I'd the same error on 10.9. I didn't had XCode installed on my system and I manually updated the XCode command line tools. After that following command fixed the error for me:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this with only mac systems since it considers running few commands such as `gcc` `git` as system level commands and part of `command line developer tools`.

I had faced this after uninstalling `xcode`. So the solution is to either install `xcode` which comes pre packed with the tools or just install the tools by running `xcode-select --install`.

Refs http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/