# installing pycrypto on mountain lion with xcode 5

Tags: python, django, pycrypto

I can't install pycrypto on mountain lion. I have command line tools installed (done from xcode 5)

When I type in `pip install pycrypto`:

.../.../ build/pycrypto':

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I've tried to symlink gcc as well as mess around with the xctoolchain, nothing is working here. Any ideas?

Comment: Try installing directly from source and examine the contents of `config.log` to see why the configure test is failing.  Also, you might have better luck with Xcode 4 command line tools.  XC 5 is not released yet and there will likely be problems using it to install various things.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reset my active Xcode to Xcode4.
You were right, XCode5 has all kinds of problems and isn't ready for primetime.
To switch back to your 'regular' XCode (Xcode 4.6 current release)

```
  sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

credit to: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961032/xcrun-error-could-not-stat-active-xcode-path-volumes-xcode-xcode45-dp1-app-c`

Now pycrypto installs perfectly.