# xcode-select --install xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'

Tags: xcode, terminal, command-line-arguments

i am trying to install Command line tools on Xcode from terminal.I am using Xcode

> Version 5.1.1 (5B1008).
>   I have installed command line tools  within Xcode,[image]

Now if i try to install Command Line tools in terminal i get this[image]

How to solve this ? xcode-select version 2311.I tried the following things

1.my path is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer,so i switched like this

> $ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer.

Nothing happened i get same error command not found.

2.I followed this link but was not useful [xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode45-DP1.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961032/xcrun-error-could-not-stat-active-xcode-path-volumes-xcode-xcode45-dp1-app-c)

Any thoughts are welcome

Comment: If you have installed the command line tools from Xcode you don't need to bother from Terminal.app.

Comment: ok.but i am trying to install Macports from terminal,where i need command line tool to install some stuff,is that ok ?what do u think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out.The problem was i was using outdated version of mavericks,i updated to the latest version and everything was working.First step is to make sure your version is up to date

Answer (score 24):

This same problem stumped me for over an hour when setting up a new MacBook Pro with the latest version of High Sierra.

The solution - curiously - was that:

- copying & pasting "xcode-select --install" failed continually, but
- typing in the same command "xcode-select --install" worked immediately.

(Someone else may understand why pasting a simple line of code did not produce the same result as entering it from the keyboard.)

Comment: Absolutely unbelievable but **true**. However, when I typed it, I got the message that the tools were already installed.

Comment: Solution replicated in Mojave.

Comment: I run into the same problem - its because the dashes are not the same... bytes of copied dashes are `\xE2\x80\x94\x2D`. Bytes of written on keyobard are normal `\x2D\x2D`

Comment: @Charlestone - Wow, what an interesting explanation of the mystery!